# Is it possible to compile project on java 8 for target java 6?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build a project on java 8, specifying java 6 as the target:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Project settings:

[image]

General IDE (Java compiler) settings:

[image]

And I wind up with the error:

> javacTask: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8

Is it possible at all to build a project on java 8 with java 6 as the target?

Comment: You cannot combine source 1.8 with target 1.6. Use 1.6 for both (assuming your source is actually Java 6)

Comment: I'm not certain of an answer, but think that you would (at least) need to change the 'Project language level' in your 'Project settings' screenshot to 6. I believe that's what IntelliJ is using to identify which features you can use, so, if you want to run on Java 6, you won't be able to use Lambdas, etc.

Comment: In theory switching both source and target to 1.6 would build your project. However to run the spring app you'd need to use the spring version and settings supported on jre 1.6

Comment: Java 8 has features not present in Java 6, including the byte code level.  This is non-trivial to get to work and you may easily run into subtle bugs.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can develop in Java 8 and target JDK 6, but it requires a bit of tweaking.

If you use a plugin like [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda), combined with backported libraries such as [StreamSupport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) and [ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/), you can use newer features on older JDKs.

Just make sure to use [Animal Sniffer](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/) to ensure you're not using newer Java API methods or classes.